# Onesignal push function is 'not a function'

Tags: push-notification, react-native, onesignal

Hey I am trying to add a tag to my onesignal user if something happens in my app, but it doesn't work, I just get this warning:

> TypeError: _reactNativeOnesignal.default.push is not a function

I am trying to do this from a different file, so I just import onesignal on top as usual and then my code looks like this:

```
OneSignal.push(function() {
      OneSignal.sendTags({
        userId: res.auth
      })
        .then(function(tagsSent) {
          // Callback called when tags have finished sending
          console.log("tag is set: ", tagsSent);
          console.log("tag shit");
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log("error", err);
        });
    });
```

and when the app hits this point i get that warning and the tag is not set.
Why is that? other than that the notifications are working as expected

Comment: how are you importing it?
import OneSignal from 'react-native-onesignal';

Comment: Where do you got that .push from? from what I see you don't need it
https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal/blob/master/examples/RNOneSignal/index.js
only sendTags

Comment: yes exactly like that

Comment: I don't see any push method in the library

Comment: from the official docs: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/add-user-data-tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.push it's for the web version, the react-native one doesn't need it, you can check it at the documentation

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk

```
// Sending single tag
OneSignal.sendTag("key", "value");

// Sending multiple tags
OneSignal.sendTags({key: "value", key2: "value2"});

// Getting the tags from the server and use the received object
OneSignal.getTags((receivedTags) => {
    console.log(receivedTags);
});

// Delete a tag
OneSignal.deleteTag("key");
// Sending single tag
OneSignal.sendTag("key", "value");

// Sending multiple tags
OneSignal.sendTags({key: "value", key2: "value2"});

// Getting the tags from the server and use the received object
OneSignal.getTags((receivedTags) => {
    console.log(receivedTags);
});

// Delete a tag
OneSignal.deleteTag("key");
```

Comment: oh thanks a lot it worked :D I will accept this as answer asap